# How I can compile Ocaml in AIX (step by step)?

Tags: ocaml, compilation, aix

It is the first time I have tried to compile something on AIX. I want to compile Ocaml to use the Unison synchronization tool. How do I compile Ocaml?

Comment: Have you read the INSTALL file ? What have you tried so far ? Where do you have trouble ?

Comment: as i say above i don't try this before i'm Unix operator so i have good information in operation  so i don't know "how to start ?" ... please if you can help me ? and thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I recommend trying [Christoph Bauer's port](http://home.arcor.de/chr_bauer/ocaml-aix.html) of Ocaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source tarball, there's a file `INSTALL` which walks you through the installation step-by-step.

Comment: Ok i read it :- i put ocaml under /usr in my system .... the first step in instalation.txt is (1- Configure the system. From the top directory, do:./configure ) put how i can execute ./configure "where it is to execute it)

Comment: You do it like this: Unpack the tarball to some temporary directory, **not** /usr. Then cd into that directory and run `./configure` and all the other commands mentioned in the document (`make world`, `make install`).

Comment: i try and it was give me the following error `./configure[173]: ../gnu/config.guess: cannot execute
Cannot guess host type
You must specify one with the -host option
`

Comment: Try `./configure --host=aix`. I'm afraid I won't be able to help you any further than that since I don't have an AIX machine.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further without access to such a system.

Comment: it looks like the ocaml is expecting GNU tools to support the installation process AND Aix doesn't come with GNU tools installed. You'll have to check with your Unix sysadmin to see if their policies allow them to install non-standard software packages on your system AND if they are allowed to do that, you'll have to give them more information about what needs to be installed. Good Luck.

Comment: after search and many tries the following error appear when i execute the command `make world opt` :- 
`        `for i in unix str num dynlink bigarray systhreads threads` `graph dbm; do  (cd otherlibs/$i; make RUNTIME= all) || exit $?; ` `done`
`"../Makefile.shared", line 40: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs ``colon or double colon operator.``
`"../Makefile.shared", line 41: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs` `colon or double colon operator.`
`make: 1254-058 Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue.`
`make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.`
`Stop.`

Comment: Sound like you're using BSD make. You need to use GNU make.